# Using .net 4.5 to create a zipped file

Tags: .net, vb.net

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the built-in zipping libraries in .net to zip a single file? The built in routines ONLY allow zipping the contents of a folder, and I looking for code that will allow one to zip up a file WITHOUT having to create a folder (temp or other wise) in which we have to COPY the files, and then create the zip file.

Every zip code library I used on planet earth has tended to allow one to select a file and then zip that file. The .net libraries force you to copy the file to a folder, and then the command of:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(strFolder, strToFile, CompressionLevel.Fastest, False)
```

So in above, the built in routines ONLY allow zipping of a folder. With LARGE files, then I have to copy all files into that folder first – this takes signification time and at the end of the day should not be required.

Does anyone know how to use the built in zip routines (.net 4.5) to zip a single file without having to copy the file into a folder?

Comment: Have you tried the [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class? It seems to do what you want.

Comment: it certainly does - I was not aware of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the `ZipFile` and its extension method [`CreateEntryFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using(var file = new FileStream(fileName)
using(var archive = new ZipArchive(zipFile)
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourceFile, fileNameInZip);
}
```

Comment: i see you like to downvote everyone just because you dont like solutions other than the ones you come up with ...

Comment: @specializt No, I downvoted you because [you gave a link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), When I you changed your answer to give it some context I removed the downvote (the current downvote you have is not from me). Also why would you say I down-vote other solutions other than the one I come up with when you and I came up with the same solution?

Comment: neither did you change my answer nor did you remove the downvote. And i said that because thats exactly what you did - downvote --> copy --> post somewhat different.

Comment: and now you're posting random links out of this topic. Hokay ... enjoy your ... agenda ... or something.

Comment: The downvote you have [is not from me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wGw4K.png) (I copied and pasted the wrong link when I was grabbing the url the first time)

Answer (score -1):

look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can just about do anything you like.

For instance, you could create a [ZipArchiveEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) inside your new [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431(v=vs.110).aspx) of your new [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A question should still be useful even if all the links go dead. At least say what you are pointing to instead of `this` and `this`.

Comment: hokay, gimme a minute